# How do I call a function from .js file with a html button?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my JavaScript file and I want to use this to mute something in my html file on the press of a button

```
//checks if its muted or not
var muteCheck = 1;

//function to mute and unmute
function mute() {  
    muteCheck = muteCheck + 1;

    if (muteCheck % 2 === 0) {
        document.getElementById("music").muted = true;
    } else if (muteCheck % 2 === 1) {
        document.getElementById("music").muted = false;
    }
}
```

This is what my html file looks like

```
<body>

    <audio autoplay loop>
        <source src="audio/something.mp3" id="music">
    </audio>

    <button type="button" id="muteButton" onclick="mute()">mute</button>

    <script src="variablesAndFunctions.js" type="text/javascript">

       mute()

    </script>

</body>
```

I opened it in Chrome, nothing happens when I press the button, nothing prints in the console or anything. I am new to coding so I don't know what I did wrong.

Any help would be appreciated thanks :D

Comment: You can't have a `<script>` element contain both the `src` attribute and inline javascript

Comment: I recommend not using a complicated if condition to mute/unmute the audio. Instead just assign `muted` to it's opposite `myElement.muted = !myElement.muted`

Comment: Try putting the javascript inside the script block, or remove the script block; don't do both

Comment: At 1st glance I thought the onclick and scope of anon function is the problem but this has so many errors it's near impossible to salvage it.

Comment: @DanteTheSmith — There's only one error that actually causes a problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `muted` on the `<source>`, not `<audio>`. The question has been edited but I believe this is the only remaining error.

Comment: "which I believe override the src" — It is the other way around. The external script causes the inline script to do nothing (which is irrevent since the question is about the button not working).

Comment: I just added the tag to the audio instead of source and it worked. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are toggling the `muted` property of the `<source>` element, but this is meaningless.

The property applies to the `<audio>` element.

```
document.getElementById("music").parentNode.muted
```

Answer (score 0):

That change would help

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="music" >
    <source src="audio/something.mp3" >
</audio>
```

Answer (score -2):

Insert this, it comes with the mute control you are look for no js required